# Using But when linking two related expressions

Tags: grammar

> I don’t think he is able to foresee the future but to see past events.

Is this grammatically correct? All I want to say is my opinion is that he is not able to foresee the future but he is able to see the past events  (The context here is it is about a fiction character from a movie)

Thanks

Comment: This is fine grammar. It sounds good to me, and not awkward.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is anything wrong with this as a matter of grammar, but it is very awkward. You can re-phrase it to make it much clearer.

> I think the character is able to see the past rather than the future.

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks for your reply. The thing is I want to emphasise that I’m pretty sure he can see the past but I’m not sure if he is able to see the future. The phrase you used doesn’t give that meaning totally. Can I say something like “I think He can’t see the future but see the past” but this time it starts with “I think” insted of “I don’t think”.

Comment: I am highly confident that he can see the past, but dubious whether he can see the future.